# jQuery load calling the complete parameter too early

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load the contents of a page into an list item using jQuery's load feature.  After it is loaded, I need to check what has been loaded. I am trying the following:

```
$('#documentLi').load('/Results/GetDocument', typeLoaded('Document'));
```

However, the typeLoaded function is executing before the load is complete.  Am I misunderstanding the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the documentation

You have actually misunderstood how JavaScript callbacks should be used. This is a common mistake. You are calling the function and using the returned value of the function as the handler (vs. the function itself). You just need to pass the function:

```
$('#documentLi').load('/Results/GetDocument', typeLoaded);
```

But since you to want the function to be called with a specific parameter, you need to wrap the snippet with another function:

```
$('#documentLi').load('/Results/GetDocument', function() {
    typeLoaded('Document');
});
```

Comment: Now I just feel dumb.

Comment: @Kevin You should not. This is a common mistake. The fact you knew the function is being called before the `load` event is complete, shows you know what you are doing.